# How to de-normalize data in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, debezium

I have a MySQL database with ~20 tables. The data is normalized.

Considering this example:

```
book -> book_authors <- authors
```

we try to stream the books info eg.:

```
{book_id:3, title='Red', authors:[{id:3, name:'Mary'}, {id:4, name:'John'}]}
```

An instance when we see a serious problem: if an author's name change, we have to re-generate all their books.
I'm using Debezium to post the change log for each table in Kafka.

I am unable to find an elegant solution for data denormalization, eg. for adding it to ElasticSearch, MongoDb etc.

I identified two solutions, but both seem to fail:

1. De-normalize data into a new MySQL table, at source, and use Debezium to stream only this new table. This might be not possible and we have to invest a lot of effort in changing the code of the source system.
2. Join the streams in Kafka, though, I didn't manage to make it work. It seems that Kafka does not allow joining on a non-primary-key field. This seems a common situation with N-to-N relations.

Did anyone find a solution to data denormalization and publish data into a Kafka stream? This seems to be a common problem and I couldn't find any solution yet.

Comment: As of Kafka 2.4, 1:n table-table joins are supported. Not sure if this might help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try publishing the changes from Debezium to the topics `book`, `book_authors` and `authors` in its raw form, which creates three disjoint streams.

Create a simple consumer application that subscribes to all three topics. Upon receiving a message on either topic, it queries the database to obtain the latest snapshot of the referenced entities, merges the data together, and publishes the denormalised version onto a new `merged_book_authors` topic. Downstream consumers can read directly from the merged topic.

A minor variation of the above: rather than querying the database for each Debezium change, which may be slow, build a **materialised view** using a fast key-value or document store such as Redis. This is a little more work, but will (1) improve the throughput of the overall pipeline and (2) take the load off the system-of-record database.